# Store Name in Magento email template

Tags: php, magento

I'm using the following code to get store name in a reminder email sent by admin.

```
$storeName = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getStore()->getName();
```

However since the email is sent via the admin the store name is coming up as **Admin** and not **Widgets.com**.

How do I get it to insert the Store Name?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$storeName = $store->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still have access to the quote (during order creation)

```
 Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getStore()->getName();
```

To get the store name by order store id

```
Mage::app()->getStore($order->getStoreId())->getName());
```